# Why does Google Chrome round all svg icons during animation with mix-blend-mode: multiply?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

On hover, only the green svg icon (first) should smoothly change its opacity to 1.
But instead, in **Google Chrome (tested on 97 and 99 version)**, all other svg icons inherit `border-radius: 25px;` for the duration of the animation, although this is not provided by anything.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  will-change: opacity;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper:hover .first {
  opacity: 1;
}

.first {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: green;
  transition: 0.5s color ease-in-out, 0.5s opacity ease-in-out;
}

.second {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background: red;
}

.third {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="first"/>
  <svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="second"/>
  <svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="third"/>
</div>
```

Example on gif:
[image]

Deleting `will-change: opacity;` makes this bug more strange:

[image]

Only deleting `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` resolve this bug:

[image]

Why it happend? How to fix it?

**This bug does not reproduce on FireFox and Safari.**

UPD: Created issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1304627

Comment: you can report Chrome bugs [on their bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/)

Comment: @RobertLongson done: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1304627 thanks.